# Matlab cross-validation on images with multiple class SVM

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to perform cross-validation on images for my SVM, where I have 3 categories of labels for the classification, "Good", "Ok" and "Bad".

For my data set, I have a 120 * 20 cell array, mainly 19 columns of features and with the last column being the class label for 120 distinct images.

The SVM train is performed using 2 different train label as such

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(normalizedTrainingSet , train_label, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
SVMStruct1 = svmtrain(normalizedTrainingSet , train_label1, 'kernel_function', 'linear');
```

Where "normalizedTrainingSet" is the numeric matrix for my data set. train_label is the label for Bad vs Normal&Good; train_label1 is the label for Good vs Normal&Bad, and I performed some if else statements to sort them out.

I want to perform cross-validation with 5 folds, and during each fold, I want to split the images equally for each category. For example, 4 for testing, and 16 for training during each fold, equally for all 3 categories.

Below is my code for the cross-validation.

```
K = 5; % The number of folds
N = size(DataSet, 1); 
idx = crossvalind('Kfold', N, K);
cp = classperf(train_label3); %train_label3 is the combination of all 3 categories in one array.

for i = 1:K
    Data_Set = DataSet(idx ~= i, :); % data to train on, 90% of the total.
    training_label = train_label3(idx ~= i, :); % class labels of training data.
    Test_Set = DataSet(idx == i, :); % data to test on, 10% of the total.
    testing_label = train_label3(idx == i, :); % class labels of test data.
```

I am stucked trying to perform the cross-validation and need some help on how to continue.